# What changes between difficulty levels?

Tags: ghost-recon-future-soldier

I've been playing through Future Soldier on Veteran, but sometimes someone watching me will comment about how much harder it is on Elite, like how that guard would have seen me, or that there was another person there with them. Said person is not known for their veracity though. What actually changes? Does it affect the combat and the stealth? In what ways?

Answer (score 1):

### 1. It’s not that hard!

It’s really not, there isn’t a huge amount of difference in the game play between elite and veteran; it’s worth playing on elite, even if you’re only slightly familiar with First Person Shooters.

### 2. Alertness

Whoever was watching you might have been correct, the alertness of the enemies increases, though not significantly. There are a lot more encounters, however if you learn to utilize your equipment, then you’ll be fine. I find on veteran that I don’t necessarily have to use that extra smoke, or flash bang at all, however on elite, you must put those items to good use.

Take note, that snipers are especially quick on the trigger in elite difficulty.

### 3. Damage Output

The damage output on elite is a tick more than on veteran. That said, even in veteran mode, you don’t want to get shot more than 2 or 3 times. I would say 1 to 2 shots and you’re down on elite (depending on what you’re shot with).

### 4. Smart AI

The AI characters on elite are more keen to working together to take you out. You’ll often find the light machine gun suppressing you as another member of their squad works his way behind you to flank you out.

They also make good use of the equipment they have and are not slow to flash or stun you. On elite, it’s hard to predict your enemies’ next action.

### 5. Timing is everything

Play smart and be aware of your surroundings. Listen to what Intel is telling you, and watch the corners. With a smart AI and an extremely advanced weapon system, *Future Soldier* is one of the easiest games, even on it’s highest difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

the difficulty level affects the enemy npc's awareness and makes them have advanced artificial intelligence. the enemy will flank, hide behind cover, and might be stronger (I'm not sure). You will also die a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

It is  easier to lower the player's health than to increase the damage output of a dozen weapons.

Enemies notice you much faster, get smarter (especially the bodarks, which will try to flank you , or attack you in groups, especially inguerilla). It's not much harder on campaign except the last part of the last mission, and some more heat packed areas. Guerilla is where you will feel the real pain!!!